# ETF performance/returns

Tags: equities, data, returns, etf, performance-evaluation

I was going over some ETF return data on yahoo finance and encountered some numbers that did not make sense to me.

The image below shows a ytd return of 17.94% and 13.52%. I checked ETF.com and ETFdb and the first number seems to be the right value. what does 13.52% represent?

Also none of the sites I check show the exact same values for return over the same period. Is this maybe because some calculate returns from market open instead of close, or could it be data issues/discrepancies from source to source?

[image]

Comment: It is very strange, it looks like the lower section "Trailing returns % vs benchmark" has not been updated in a month. The YTD return was 13.53% ON MARCH 29, 2019". Similarly the 1-month return of 1.81% is the correct return FOR THE MONTH OF MARCH (!), although today is May 1st. Possibly these errors will be corrected tonight or in the next few days as they update their website for the start of a new month.

Comment: Look at the YTD performance and the 3 month performance: they are the same, which confirms what I am saying: these figures are as of the end of March.

Answer (score 1):

Any number of reasons...between vendors, could be small pricing discrepancies, calc differences, etc.  Within a given system, it's likely attributable to update frequency.  I've seen some providers with data published that was months old.  Per the comments, looks like this falls into that camp.  When in doubt, download returns and do the calculations yourself.